# how to change the keyword for URL search with new search

Tags: search, uri

I have a problem with the search API function. The first time I enter the keyword into the search field which will show the results and the URL like this for example:
www.avc.com/avs/search/search-content?keys=city
If I enter the new keyword to search (ex: search for "water", it will show the result, but the URL does not change the keyword. When you click on any result and then click go back it will go to the first search (city).
How can I make the URL change the keyword?

Comment: You probably have use ajax enabled for the view.  This works faster than reloading the page.  Turning it off should make the page reload with a new URL/search term.

Comment: Thanks, I got it worked now.